# display image using dropdown list from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, image, display

When i select name of a product, i want to display the image with the product

I select the product with this code :

```
<tr>
    <td>Produs:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="combo2">
            <option selected value="initial">Alege produsul</option>
            <?php
            include("conn.php");
            class produse {
                public $id_produs;
                public $numep;
            }

            if(isset($cnx)) {
                $cda= "SELECT * FROM produse order by numep ASC";
                $stmt = $cnx->prepare($cda);
                $stmt->execute();
                while ($categ = $stmt->fetchObject('produse')) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $categ->id_produs . '">' . $categ->numep. '</option>\n';
                }
                $cnx = null;
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

After this selection i need to see a image of the product.

...
this is the table with product and images: 
SELECT * FROM `produse` WHERE 1`id_produs`, `numep`, `standard`, `fisa_tehnica`, `pret`

and the images are: `fisa_tehnica`
link for images is this:  C:\xampp\htdocs\cerasind\imagini

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer; too long for a comment:

This is nonsense, which renders the rest of the incomprehensible:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `produse` 
 WHERE 1`id_produs`
     , `numep`
     , `standard`
     , `fisa_tehnica`
     , `pret`
```